# Can iFrames work on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iframe

I have read so much and still no real answer. How can I get iFrames to work on the iPhone and iPad? Especially now you can't 2 finger scroll. I just want to have an iFrame scroll or something that functions like one. I feel like this should be so simple!

Here is a sample page:

http://olbrichdesigns.com/ffff/characters/test.html

Thanks!
jenny

Answer (score 6):

Mobile safari supports them but generally they're not great.

Using a DIV with overflow-y: scroll would probably be better for you

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at laoreet augue.     Pellentesque felis arcu, convallis eu luctus vitae, imperdiet ut est. Nulla rhoncus varius odio, non facilisis felis imperdiet pellentesque. Aliquam in luctus orci. Ut convallis felis sodales diam ultricies in elementum ligula ultricies. Vivamus consequat convallis mauris, sed ullamcorper ante fermentum a. Quisque at velit eu velit venenatis faucibus id vel velit. Integer eget nisi elit. Ut blandit eros lorem, sed feugiat nunc. Sed lacus nisi, placerat sit amet blandit feugiat, accumsan ut urna. Proin risus sapien, porttitor sed euismod quis, adipiscing vitae nulla. Vestibulum at ipsum vel tortor fermentum tristique. Fusce laoreet magna vitae tellus accumsan eget adipiscing velit ullamcorper. Proin tempus volutpat fringilla. Etiam eu magna sit amet mi commodo volutpat sit amet eget lacus. Nullam euismod tellus id odio tempus id tincidunt felis mollis.
</div>
```

​

Comment: I don't understand. It's a new world for me.

Comment: I have included an example above.

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could be of assistance.